# primefaces calender not invoking valuechangelistener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

here is the code snipprt

```xml
<p:calendar 
    id="from" 
    value="#{documentInsertController.from}"
    yearRange="1900:2015"
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
    mindate="#{documentInsertController.today}"
    valueChangeListener="#{documentInsertController.calenderChangeListener}"
>
    <p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="from" render="to"/>
</p:calendar>
```

This is the actionlister method in bean class

```cs
public void calenderChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {    
    System.out.println("Calender Change Listener Invoked: " + e.getNewValue());
}
```

I want to know what is missing and why it is not invoking the action method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `<p:ajax event="dateSelect"`

Like this (I removed the `partialSubmit="from"` and instead of `render` changed into `update` because its `p:ajax` and not `f:ajax`

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect"  
        listener="#{documentInsertController.calenderChangeListener}" 
        update="to"/>
```

Also change your method signature into:

```
public void calenderChangeListener(SelectEvent event) {
    Date date = event.getDate();
    System.out.println("File Date: " + date);
    System.out.println("Hello... I am in DateChange");
}
```

Comment: I was waiting for you Daniel :) let me check

Comment: my eclipse is not recognizing `DateSelectEvent` class

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using ? is it present in your project Build Path

Comment: i am using 3.5 .. yes it is in classpath .. my other primefaces controls are working fine

Comment: if you can't import `import org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent;` it means that your primefaces jar in not in your class path... do a double check try to remove/add refresh etc...

Comment: I did all this.Please have a look here [Remove DateSelectEvent in favor of SelectEvent](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5044) i guess this event has removed in 3.5 version

Comment: Ohh... my fault , still using 3.4 and was not aware of that change , use `SelectEvent event` in your method signature... Updated my answer

Comment: now in 3.5 and it is `import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;` see this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarAjax.jsf

Comment: Use SelectEvent inplace of DateSelectEvent as suggested by Bomb as it is depricated. Which can be imported by "import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;" Then use it as Date date = (Date)event.getObject();

Comment: @Daniel I must accept this answer as you lead me to the right path :) thanks